# Kubernetes kubectl set image deployment not able to --record history?

Tags: image, deployment, kubernetes, record, history

According to the user guide it should be possible to [update a deployment's image](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#updating-a-deployment) with `kubectl set/edit` and still get a meaningful [history](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/deployments/#checking-rollout-history-of-a-deployment).

However i'm getting some errors instead, and no meaningful history, could this be a bug?

```
$ kubectl create -f kubernetes/deployment.yml --record
deployment "nginx" created

$ kubectl set image deployment/nginx nginx=nginx:0.2.0
deployment "nginx" image updated
changes to deployments/nginx can't be recorded: Operation cannot be fulfilled on deployments.extensions "nginx": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try againc

$ kubectl set image deployment/nginx nginx=nginx:0.2.1
deployment "nginx" image updated
changes to deployments/nginx can't be recorded: Operation cannot be fulfilled on deployments.extensions "nginx": the object has been modified; please apply your changes to the latest version and try again

$ kb rollout history deployment/nginx
deployments "nginx":
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1   kubectl create -f kubernetes/deployment.yml --record
2   kubectl create -f kubernetes/deployment.yml --record
3   kubectl create -f kubernetes/deployment.yml --record

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"3", GitVersion:"v1.3.0+2831379", GitCommit:"283137936a498aed572ee22af6774b6fb6e9fd94", GitTreeState:"not a git tree", BuildDate:"2016-07-05T15:40:13Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"3", GitVersion:"v1.3.0", GitCommit:"283137936a498aed572ee22af6774b6fb6e9fd94", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2016-07-01T19:19:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.6.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is due to update conflict when we update the deployment's annotation (for recording its change history). This means that the deployment object is modified (most likely by server) when `kubectl` updates the deployment change history. `kubectl set image` currently won't retry change history update on conflict for you.

I've filed a [fix](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/29300) to mitigate this.

Comment: I had this issue with 1.3.0, but I can confirm this is now fixed with 1.3.4.

Comment: I'm getting this issue on 1.3.6.

Comment: I'm also getting this issue on 1.3.6.

Comment: This fix will be in 1.4.0 (soon to be released)